# Can I get the index of a header cell for an angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can I replace [0] with the actual index of the header cell within the table?

something like [ngClass]="{'highlight':highlightedRows **[this.elem.cellIndex]** }"

Here is the code

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell 
      *matHeaderCellDef
      (click)="highlightColumn($event)"
      [ngClass]="{'highlight':highlightedRows[0]}"
    > No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
    [ngClass]="{'highlight':highlightedRows[0]}"

    > {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change the  to this:

```
*matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"
```

Then, you can use i in place of the 0.

Comment: wouldn't that make i always 0, unless I put the columns in an array and loop them, There is no loop on the header cells currently

Comment: You're correct.  This doesn't solve the header problem, but it does solve the detail problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that You need redesign You table and use something like this. Create columns using *ngFor

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay, let i = index">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} {{i}}</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

More You make find here https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples in expandable table